# The curvature tensor in the general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I have recently faced an ambiguity in understanding Einstein's general relativity. Before all, I apologize if my question is duplicate or off-topic, but I equally appreciate any resource to find answers to my questions.

**Background to my question:** we already know that the Riemann's curvature tensor $R^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\theta}$ provides sufficient information about the curvature of any metric space. To relate gravity (spacetime curvature) to stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, one must reduce two of the subscripts of $R^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\theta}$ through proper raising and lowering of the indices to obtain a new tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$. So far, the proper field equations should be
$$
R_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu},
$$
which does not hold because of the conservation of $T_{\mu\nu}$. Hence, an extra tensor component should be added to the left side, In case of Einstein's field equation, it becomes
$$
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}
,
$$
where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor.

**My question is**:

How did Einstein come upon deciding that $R_{\mu\nu}$ should be defined from $R^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\theta}$ through a contraction of the superscript with its second subscript? For example, why is defining $R_{\mu\nu}$ as $R^{\alpha}_{\alpha\mu\nu}$ or $R^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu\alpha}$ out of value?

Comment: Note that, $R^\alpha_{\alpha \mu \nu}=0$, and $R^\alpha_{\mu \nu \alpha} = -R^{\alpha}_{\mu \alpha \nu}$. Have you gone through the derivation of the [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Conservation_of_energy_and_momentum)?

Comment: Not so much. So, the reason for choosing the Ricci tensor is that it is the only choice, right?

Comment: Ricci tensor is the simplest choice, other alternatives are complicated - like the higher derivative gravity.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? Contractions of the Riemann curvature tensor seems to be pure math.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to you question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/236093/